# Removing an item from DataContext and showing the updated values WITHOUT SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm

I have in my *WPF* form a `DataGrid` that is showing items from a `DataContext` via *Binding*. I have added a column with delete buttons that are bound to a command in the *ViewModel* that is supposed to remove the item from the context, and update the `DataGrid` accordingly.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding Quiz.Questionnaire}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vraag" Binding="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aantal antwoorden" Binding="{Binding AnswerCount, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteRow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public void DeleteRowCommand(object row)
    {
        if(row is QuestionVM question)
        {
            _Context.Questions.Remove(question.ToModel);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Quiz.Questionnaire));
        }
        else if(row is AnswerVM answer)
        {
            _Context.Answers.Remove(answer.ToModel);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Answers));
        }
    }
```

- I've confirmed that the code properly calls the method, so it's not a problem with the *Binding*.
- I've confirmed that the database does get properly updated with I click my button that contains the `DataContext.SaveChanges()`.

What I want, however, is that the `DataGrid` removes the item from the list **before** I save the changes. So that I can still discard the changes if I want to.

**Update**

Basically I'm trying to create an *Edit* window in which I can edit an item however I want, and then either confirm my changes or change my mind and go back to the previous view and discard all the changes I've made.

To that end, I have my *Edit* window's *ViewModel* create its own instance of the `DataContext`. If I click the *Save Changes* button, that context is sent back to the previous window and the database is updated accordingly, but if I press *Discard Changes*, I simply close the window and continue with the old, unedited context.

To be clear, right now I just want the Delete button mentioned in the OP to immediately remove (visually) its row from the `DataGrid` list

Comment: Nicely worded question **upvote**, however can you be a little more specific with the last paragraph, specifically "*So that I can still discard the changes if I want to*" . Do you mean in 2 steps / 2 actions? please elaborate

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create an Edit window in which I can edit an item however I want, and then either confirm my changes or change my mind and go back to the previous view and discard all the changes I've made. To that end I have my Edit window's ViewModel create its own instance of the DataContext. If I click the Save Changes button, that context is sent back to the previous window and the database is updated accordingly, but if I press Discard Changes, I simply close the window and continue with the old, unedited context.

Comment: To be clear, right now I just want the Delete button mentioned in the OP to immediately remove (visually) its row from the DataGrid list.

Comment: Ok that that's clear enough, one of the DataGrid minions will be with you shortly

Comment: How about using an explicit transaction with the same DbContext? Start the transaction before the edit, but only commit on "Save".

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not trigger the DataGrid to update its list, even when I call SaveChanges() before the RaisePropertyChanged().

Comment: Can you please share the definition of property `Quiz.Questionnaire` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Questions and Answers containers as `ObservableCollections`. The the U.I. controls will automatically update when an item is added or removed. No need for RaisePropertyChanged() calls in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually already had my properties stored as ObservableCollections, but I mistakenly thought my DataGrid was reading data from the DbContext and didn't consider this obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a property to your item class.

```
bool PendingDelete {get; set;} = false;
```

Then use a CollectionViewFilter to filter out all items marked to be deleted.
Pressing the delete button would mark the item for deletion as well as refresh the CollectionView.

When the actual commit command takes place query your collection for all items marked for deletion and process them.